# Android Runtime.getRuntime().exec command causes app to freeze before getting an output

Tags: java, android, unix, ping

I'am trying to Build an app that can ping servers and get latency. For which

```java
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(pingCommand);
```

command calls a `system/bin/ping -c` command.

So, when I press Calculate *(A button that i use)* from UI, it freezes the app until the exec is completed. How do i fix the freeze so that it can allow me to close my keyboard while the answer is fetched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid UI freezes run in thread

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            try {
                // Send script into runtime process
                Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(pingCommand);

                // ......

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                // .....
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

**Alternative**

You can use `AsyncTask` like this:

```
private class YourTasksClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {


    private String cmd;

    public YourTasksClass(String command) {
        this.cmd = command;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {


        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

            // ....

            String someResult = "some kind of result";

            return someResult;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if(result != null) {
            Log.d("tag", "Result: " + result);
        }

    }
}
```

Later in your code, you can call this by:

```
new YourTasksClass(pingCommand).execute();
```

Comment: I am using a thread for my Runtime Requests. Still. Could it be because im waiting for it in the ui thread for my answer to display in textview?

Comment: Yes sure. all traitement should be async, otherwise, your UI will freeze, since it's waiting for the response to complete.

Answer (score 0):

you are doing network request in UI thread, so it is freezing because of waiting for response (and keeping connection alive)

use any of async ways to do network stuff, best way for you will be [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) (move your network-related method calls to `doInBackground` method, publish results in `onPostExecute`)

Comment: Could you please elaborate, how can i give values in it parameter and or recieve a return?

Comment: see edit in another answer, mine would be similar :)